# Type: Error Message: Call to undefined function str_contains()

Tags: php

Tengo un error en codeigniter, este error me dice que falla en la llamada de la función `str_contains()` esta función es nativa de *PHP* lo extraño es que me funciona en *Windows* pero no en *Ubuntu*.

> An uncaught Exception was encountered
>
> Type: Error
>
> Message: Call to undefined function str_contains()
>
> Filename: /var/www/html/academusoft/application/views/acta_homologacion.php
>
> Line Number: 241

Esta es mi línea de código donde da el error ahí se ve la función que uso.

```
 if (!str_contains($info['programa_uvi'], 'EMPRESAS') || str_contains($info['programa_uvi'], 'TECNICO PROFESIONAL')) {
                           if (str_contains($info['programa_uvi'], 'TECNICO')) {
```

Comment: ¿Qué versión de PHP  usas en tu Ubuntu?

Comment: PHP Version 7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.7

Comment: A pues por eso, esa función solo existe en [php 8](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-contains.php)

Comment: jejeje muchas gracias no sabia eso.

Comment: En la parte superior de la [documentación oficial de `str_contains()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-contains.php) te aparece la compatibilidad, y con cada instrucción hace lo mismo.

Comment: @franmost el enlace que provees no brinda información al respecto de la función, tal vez tiene algún detalle

Comment: PErdona @BetaM, se me da mal hacer estas cosas y necesito ir probando. Intento aprender :)